# Aggregate values from dataframe based on a on criteria if not null

Tags: python, pandas, join, pyspark, aggregate

I have trouble building a custom aggregation with the caveat that my join keys are different on each row. Can someone help me please?

I have been stuck with a problemm for some time. I have a huge dataframe with transactions which has a format close to this:

```
flat_data = {
    'year': [2022, 2022, 2022, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023],
    'month': [1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
    'operator': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
    'value': [10, 15, 20, 8, 12, 15, 30, 40, 50],
    'attribute1': ['x', 'x', 'y', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'x', 'z', 'x'],
    'attribute2': ['apple', 'apple', 'banana', 'apple', 'banana', 'banana', 'apple', 'banana', 'banana'],
    'attribute3': ['dog', 'cat', 'dog', 'cat', 'rabbit', 'tutle', 'cat', 'dog', 'dog'],
}
```

I have over 80 attributes.

On the other hand I have a totals dataframe looking like this:

```
totals= {
    'year': [2022, 2022, 2023, 2023, 2023],
    'month': [1, 2, 1, 2, 3],
    'operator': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
    'id': ['id1', 'id2', 'id1', 'id2', 'id3'], 
    'attribute1': [None, 'y', 'x', 'z', 'x'],
    'attribute2': ['apple', None, 'apple', 'banana', 'banana'],
}
```

The totals dataframe has only attributes I can find the in flat_data but has an extra id. What I am trying to do is to get a result dataframe with year, month, operator id and value. For that I need to sum the values of all rows of flat that match the attributes of filter but only the non-null ones.

My output looks like:

```
result= {
    'year': [2022, 2022, 2023, 2023, 2023],
    'month': [1, 2, 1, 2, 3],
    'operator': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
    'id': ['id1', 'id2', 'id1', 'id2', 'id3'],
     'sum': [10, 15, 20, 8, 12, 15, 30, 40, 50],
}
```

where sum is a sum of all values of rows where the non null attributes match the id attributes.

For example id1  would match every row of 01/2002 with the same operator (oroperator A) with attribute2 = apple regardlless of attribute 1 (rows 1 and 2)  so my total for id 1 for operator A for 01/2022 would be 25.

I tried looping through the rows but it is prone to error and memory greedy. I want to try to use pyspark but cannot find how to distribute the task.
I have managed to do it on a row by row basis. Meaning a join on attributes and then groupby + sum. However where I am stuck is that in effect each row has its own set of join keys because of the null constraint (i.e. null in filter matches everything)and I cannot therefore generalise the approach.

Comment: can you please give a more clear example of what you want the output file to be? do you need to have any of the attribute columns in your output?  what is the exact issue that is holding you back or what have you tried so far?

Comment: No problem I added the info in the post, To be specific, I gave the format I am looking for, regarding attributes outside the ones I explicitly name no all can go. And while I can do it inn a very inefficient mannner row by row, I was looking for a more efficient approach because I ry to avoir large for loops.

Comment: Are you sure the `sum` column of `result` is correctly jotted down? It has 9 elements whereas other columns(keys of `result` dictionary) have 5 elements.

Comment: No indeed the results are fake, in fact I do now know the results on my real data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understand the question correctly. Check out this solution:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("pyspark_playground").getOrCreate()

flat_data = {
    'year': [2022, 2022, 2022, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023],
    'month': [1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
    'operator': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
    'value': [10, 15, 20, 8, 12, 15, 30, 40, 50],
    'attribute1': ['x', 'x', 'y', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'x', 'z', 'x'],
    'attribute2': ['apple', 'apple', 'banana', 'apple', 'banana', 'banana', 'apple', 'banana', 'banana'],
    'attribute3': ['dog', 'cat', 'dog', 'cat', 'rabbit', 'tutle', 'cat', 'dog', 'dog'],
}
totals= {
    'year': [2022, 2022, 2023, 2023, 2023],
    'month': [1, 2, 1, 2, 3],
    'operator': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
    'id': ['id1', 'id2', 'id1', 'id2', 'id3'], 
    'attribute1': [None, 'y', 'x', 'z', 'x'],
    'attribute2': ['apple', None, 'apple', 'banana', 'banana'],
}
flat_data_df = spark.createDataFrame(list(zip(*flat_data.values())), list(flat_data.keys()))
totals_df = spark.createDataFrame(list(zip(*totals.values())), list(totals.keys()))

output_df = (
    flat_data_df.alias('flat')
    .join(
        totals_df.alias('total'), 
        (flat_data_df.year == totals_df.year) & 
        (flat_data_df.month == totals_df.month) & 
        (flat_data_df.operator == totals_df.operator) & 
        ((flat_data_df.attribute1 == totals_df.attribute1) | (totals_df.attribute1.isNull())) & 
        ((flat_data_df.attribute2 == totals_df.attribute2) | (totals_df.attribute2.isNull())), 
        "inner"
    )
    .select('flat.year', 'flat.month', 'flat.operator', 'total.id', 'flat.value') 
    .groupBy('year', 'month', 'operator', 'id')
    .agg(f.sum('value').alias('sum'))
)

output_df.show()
```

and the output is:

```
+----+-----+--------+---+---+                                                   
|year|month|operator| id|sum|
+----+-----+--------+---+---+
|2022|    1|       A|id1| 25|
|2022|    2|       B|id2| 20|
|2023|    1|       A|id1|  8|
|2023|    2|       B|id2| 15|
|2023|    3|       C|id3| 50|
+----+-----+--------+---+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    import pandas as pd
flat_data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
    'year': [2022, 2022, 2022, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023],
    'month': [1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
    'operator': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
    'value': [10, 15, 20, 8, 12, 15, 30, 40, 50],
    'attribute1': ['x', 'x', 'y', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'x', 'z', 'x'],
    'attribute2': ['apple', 'apple', 'banana', 'apple', 'banana', 'banana', 'apple', 'banana', 'banana'],
    'attribute3': ['dog', 'cat', 'dog', 'cat', 'rabbit', 'tutle', 'cat', 'dog', 'dog'],
})
print('The dataset below is your flat_data:')
print(flat_data)
totals= pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
    'year': [2022, 2022, 2023, 2023, 2023],
    'month': [1, 2, 1, 2, 3],
    'operator': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
    'id': ['id1', 'id2', 'id1', 'id2', 'id3'], 
    'attribute1': [None, 'y', 'x', 'z', 'x'],
    'attribute2': ['apple', None, 'apple', 'banana', 'banana'],
})
print('The dataset below is your totals:')
print(totals)
flat_data_aggregated = flat_data.groupby(['year','month','operator']).agg({'value':'mean'}).rename(columns={'value':'value'}).reset_index()
print('The dataset below aggregates the value column for each year, month, and operator removing the null values, using your flat_data:')
print(flat_data_aggregated)         
results = pd.merge(flat_data_aggregated, totals[['year','month','operator','id']],  how='left', on=['year','month','operator'])
print('This is the results dataset after merging the two datasets:')
print(results)
```

[image]